# Select a valid choice. XYZ is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model for adding entries of Mobile apps:

```
class MobileApp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank=True)
```

In Django Admin, what i am trying to do is filter the images that are listed in the list to prevent django from loading all images in that table which are quite alot.

So what i currently do is the following:

```
class MobileAppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MobileAppAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        if obj:
            form.base_fields['images'].queryset = Image.objects.filter(pk__in=obj.images.all())
        else:
            form.base_fields['images'].queryset = Image.objects.filter(pk=0)
        return form
```

But when submitting the form, adding a new image, what happens is the following:

```
Select a valid choice. XYZ is not one of the available choices.
```

On the images field.

How can i make this work? i have lots of fields that need the same move as django keeps loading all the records to populate the lists for relations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't limit options when form being submitted.

```
class MobileAppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MobileAppAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if obj:
                form.base_fields['images'].queryset = Image.objects.filter(pk__in=obj.images.all())
            else:
                form.base_fields['images'].queryset = Image.objects.filter(pk=0)
        return form
```